# Не работает PHP (Работа с картинками,сжатие)

Tags: php

Всем привет!
У меня есть такой вот клас для сжатия картинки:

```
 class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {
      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {
         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {
      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {
      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {
      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }
}
```

Он работает, тоесть абсолютно исправен.

Но вот когда  пытаюсь получить изображение из видео, то происходит ошибка (код вообще не работает, вместо картинки тупо черный обьект)

```
    $res1 = '332'; //ширина
$res2 = '184'; //высота
 $moment_s = (15 * $x);
 $movie = new ffmpeg_movie(H . "video/video/" . $file['id'] . "" . $file['ext'] . "");
 $frames_count  = $movie->getFrameCount();
 $frames_rate = $movie->getFrameRate();
 $seconds = ceil($frames_count/$frames_rate);

  for($k=1; $k<=$seconds-15; $k=$k+$moment_s){
              $frame = ceil($k*$frames_rate);
              echo $frame."<br>";
              $image = $movie->getFrame($frame);
              $show_img = $image->toGDImage();
              #imagejpeg($show_img, H . "video/foto/mini/" . $file['id'] . "_" . $x . ".png");
               $image = new SimpleImage();
               $image->load($show_img);
               $image->resize($res1, $res2);
               $image->save(H . "video/foto/mini/" . $file['id'] . "_" . $x . ".png");
            }
```

Прошу помочь)

Comment: Какое значение у `$this->image_type`?

Comment: вот весь код https://pastebin.com/4SWA1zyz